# Capybara undefined method 'current_scope'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I have the following code

```
scenario "it should not appears submenus' links if it doesn't has any" do
  expect(page.find('li.main-category', text: "Stargazing")).not_to have_tag('ul.nested')
end
```

and when I run the test I get this error

```
 NoMethodError:
 undefined method `current_scope' for #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x0055d1ab86e430>
```

I am trying  to test this code

```
<ul class="menu vertical">
   <li class="main-category"><a href="#">Solar System</a>
     <ul class="nested vertical menu">
       <li class="subcategory"><a href="#">Planets</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="main-category"><a href="#">Stargazing</a></li>
</ul>
```

The *li* tag with text 'Stargazing' should not contain a *ul* tag

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what library the `have_tag` matcher you're using is coming from, but that's not a Capybara matcher and is not compatible with Capybara.  You want

```
expect(page.find('li.main-category', text: "Stargazing")).not_to have_css('ul.nested')
```

or `have_css('ul')` if you are trying to make sure there are no ul elements at all, and not just no ul elements with a class of nested.

Also make sure your Capybara is updated.